# How to set session variable skip_unusable_indexes to true in a PL/SQL package to speed up a table delete/insert?

Tags: oracle, session, plsql, indexing

I'm trying to speed up a data load which is controlled via a PL/SQL stored procedure.  I've programmatically altered the indexes for the table I want to refresh to be unusable. I want Oracle to ignore these unusable indexes.  I can issue the statement:

```
ALTER SESSION SET skip_unusable_indexes = TRUE
```

but I subsequently get the error:

> ORA-01502: index 'MY_INDEX_NAME' or partition of such index is in
>   unusable state

so is it seems to have ignored my alter session.

Can I alter my session inside a PL/SQL package?  If not, what is my alternative?
How else might I disable (set unusable) the indexes to speed up the load?

A somewhat related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129046/disable-and-later-enable-all-table-indexes-in-oracle).

Comment: Seems the answer is... you can't.

Answer (score 4):

Are you issuing the ALTER SESSION statement in the same session that the stored procedure is using?  Or is that ALTER SESSION executed in a separate session?

You can embed the ALTER SESSION in your PL/SQL with dynamic SQL, i.e.

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET skip_unusable_indexes = TRUE';

  <<more code>>
END;
```

Are some of the indexes unique (or used to enforce a unique constraint)?  As the [skip_unusable_indexes documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams200.htm#REFRN10240) states

> Note: If an index is used to enforce a
>   UNIQUE constraint on a table, then
>   allowing insert and update operations
>   on the table might violate the
>   constraint. Therefore, this setting
>   does not disable error reporting for
>   unusable indexes that are unique.

If that is the case, can you disable the constraint and/or change the index(es) to be non-unique?

A quick sample of the difference between unique and non-unique indexes.  Note when you have an unusable unique index, skip_unusable_indexes does not suppress the ORA-01502 error as it does when you have an unusable non-unique index.

```
SQL> create table a (
  2    col1 number
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> create unique index idx_a on a( col1 );

Index created.

SQL> insert into a values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter index idx_a unusable;

Index altered.

SQL> insert into a values( 2 );
insert into a values( 2 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01502: index 'SCOTT.IDX_A' or partition of such index is in unusable state


SQL> alter session set skip_unusable_indexes = true;

Session altered.

SQL> insert into a values( 2 );
insert into a values( 2 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01502: index 'SCOTT.IDX_A' or partition of such index is in unusable state


SQL> drop index idx_a;

Index dropped.

SQL> create index idx_a_nonunique on a( col1 );

Index created.

SQL> alter index idx_a_nonunique unusable;

Index altered.

SQL> insert into a values( 2 );

1 row created.
```

Comment: Tried that originally, but it still gives me the ORA-01502 error.

Comment: I don't think that is relevant, the ORA-01502 error is complaining that the index is unusable (which is intended) not that a unique constraint has been violated.

Comment: But that's the point of the statement "this setting does not disable error reporting for unusable indexes that are unique".  See the edit I just made with a demonstration.

Comment: Ok, I see your point.  So I tried disabling the unique constraints and running again, but the ORA-01502 still crops up.

Comment: I believe so, but I've moved on.  I'm satisfied with the speed without any additional alteration to the indexing.  Thanks for all your advise.