# Cannot disable index during PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've written a PL/SQL procedure that would benefit if indexes were first disabled, then rebuilt upon completion. An [existing thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129046/disable-and-later-enable-all-table-indexes-in-oracle) suggests this approach:

```
alter session set skip_unusable_indexes = true;

alter index your_index unusable;
```

[do import]

```
alter index your_index rebuild;
```

However, I get the following error on the first `alter index` statement:

```
SQL Error: ORA-14048: a partition maintenance operation may not be combined with other operations
ORA-06512: [...]
14048. 00000 -  "a partition maintenance operation may not be combined with other operations"
*Cause:    ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX statement attempted to combine
           a partition maintenance operation (e.g. MOVE PARTITION) with some
           other operation (e.g. ADD PARTITION or PCTFREE which is illegal
*Action:   Ensure that a partition maintenance operation is the sole
           operation specified in ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX statement;
           operations other than those dealing with partitions,
           default attributes of partitioned tables/indices or
           specifying that a table be renamed (ALTER TABLE RENAME) may be
           combined at will
```

The problem index is defined so:

```
CREATE INDEX A11_IX1 ON STREETS ("SHAPE")
  INDEXTYPE IS "SDE"."ST_SPATIAL_INDEX" PARAMETERS
  ('ST_GRIDS=890,8010,72090 ST_SRID=2');
```

This is a custom index type from a 3rd-party vendor, and it causes chronic performance degradation during high-volume update/insert/delete operations.

Any suggestions on how to work around this error? By the way, this error only occurs within a PL/SQL block.

**Edit:** Here is the procedure in its entirety:

```
procedure disable_indexes (
  tbl_name in varchar2
) as
  stmt varchar2(200);
  cursor curs(v_tbl_name in varchar2) is
    select 'alter index ' || index_name || ' unusable;' as ddl_stmt
    from user_indexes
    where upper(table_owner) = upper(user)
    and upper(table_name) = upper(v_tbl_name)
    and ityp_name in ('CTXCAT', 'ST_SPATIAL_INDEX');
begin
  for r_curs in curs(tbl_name) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_curs.ddl_stmt);
    execute immediate r_curs.ddl_stmt;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: From the subject, I guessed that you are trying to disable the index within the PL/SQL procedure which is a DDL and could only be achieved with an `execute immediate '...'`. However, since you don't mention something like this, I guess you do the DDLs outside of the PL/SQL procedure. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is really your code and not a pseudo-code rewrite, remove the `;` at the end of your statement in the `stmt` variable (otherwise you will run into `ORA-00911: invalid character` during execution)

Now if your process works manually, you should be able to make it work with `execute immediate` in a procedure. Make sure that this is not a role issue (see this [article by Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551289900368934430)) by issuing `SET ROLE NONE` before executing the commands manually.

Comment: Good catch. Would you believe that removing the `;` solved the problem? I cannot fathom why Oracle was giving me on `ORA-14048` error.

Comment: Sadly, almost anyone who has worked with Oracle would believe that the error message received has nothing to do with the actual problem.  <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a DROP INDEX before and then recreate it after?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid.